# How do I install Solaris 10 on a Sunblade 150 machine using external DVD drive?

Tags: solaris, system-installation, opensolaris

I want to install Solaris 10 on a Sunblade 150 Machine. It comes on a CD-ROM. Can I install it using an external DVD-drive?

Comment: what have you tried to do??? as far as I remember from external DVD drive it will be extremely slow to install Solaris. I believe your drive will be usb, if so it is at most usb 1.1. Be prepared to leave it overnight.

Comment: Wauw. That is some old hw. If you need to play around or develop stuff for Solaris why not simply install Solaris inside VirtualBox?  But of course if you **need** it to be SPARC rather than X86 then I understand. :-)

Comment: What OS is currently installed ? What are the sizes of the harddisk and RAM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.  As I recall, the last PROM code for the Sun Blade 100/150 didn't support booting from USB devices.  You can buy a 50-pin SCSI DVD-ROM drive from Ebay for anywhere from $20 - $100.  Example: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Pioneer-DVD-116SM-Sun-370-4439-50-pin-SCSI-16x-DVD-ROM-Drive-523424739017-/161001660487?pt=US_CD_DVD_Blu_Ray_Drives&hash=item257c726047

The only other option would be to set up a jumpstart server, and `boot net - install`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and see if it registers and if you can mount the drive [like so](http://www.crucial.com.au/blog/2010/02/19/how-to-mount-a-cddvd-drive-in-solaris/)? Surely there is a way using the `boot` [command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2240/boot-1m/index.html). Alternatives include a network install or making the iso media file available in the OS where you could simply [mount](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2240/lofiadm-1m/) it then perform an update of the software directly from the machine using [luupgrade](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2240/luupgrade-1m/index.html) like [here](http://jibbysununix.blogspot.ca/2010/09/solaris-10-live-upgrade-to-solaris10.html) for example. I [read](http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/32755-can-i-reboot-sunblade150-cd.html) you can access the *ok* prompt on the boot screen by pressing `STOP+A` on the original keyboard. I guess it all depends on your setup and assets available... like a [jumpstart](http://www.adminschoice.com/solaris-jumpstart-howto-guide/) software server which can be installed with the install media on another machine if I understand correctly.

Maybe specificy the type of external DVD drive?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Blade 150s boot from USB.

But, the good news is blade 150s take IDE drives, so you should be able to grab a surplus CD/DVD drive and put it in the 150.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Sun workstations are "fussy" when it comes to working with third-party hardware. Check the Sun Systems Handbook and hardware compatibility list before trying a USB DVD-ROM drive. We had SB 150s when I worked for Sun. USB devices (mind you this was when S10u5 was out) meant extra hoops to jump through if you were lucky. Also be mindful of the update release of S10 you are installing and obviously check out the readme before installing. Mr. Kennedy's Jumpstart suggestion would be the best overall.

Answer (score 0):

When I had an Ultra 5, I was able to use a commodity DVD-ROM drive for the system, and OpenBoot had no problem with it.

Same thing when I used a commodity IDE DVD-ROM drive for a Sun Blade 2500 Red.